# Binary search an element (with duplicate items) in a 2D array column-wise sorted?

Tags: java, binary-search

**EDIT:**

For the 2D array, **only column were sorted** but not sorted for rows. Below is the method I wrote, first binary search each column, then go through every column and also count the duplicate element.But the code does not work for me. Does anyone can help me? Many thanks!

```
public static int count(int[][] array, int query) {

    int count = 0;

    for (int j = 0; j < array[0].length; j++) {
        count += biSearch(array, query, j);
    }

    return count;
}

private static int biSearch(int[][] array, int searchItem, int row) {

    // create a 1D array to hold the entries of 2D array's column
    int[] column = new int[array.length];
    int count = 0;
    int low = 0;
    int high = column.length - 1;

    // put 2D array's column into 1D array
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        column[i] = array[i][row];

    // binary search on column array
    while (low < high) {
        int mid = (low + high) / 2;

        if ( column[mid]== searchItem ) {
            while ((mid - 1) >= 0) {
                if (column[mid - 1] == searchItem){ 
                    mid--;
                    count++;
                }
            }
            while ((mid + 1) < (column.length - 1)) {
                if (column[mid + 1] == searchItem){ 
                    mid++;
                    count++;
                }
            }
        } 
        else if ( column[mid] > searchItem)
            high = mid - 1;
        else if (column[mid] <searchItem )
            low = mid + 1;
    }

    return count;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work? Do you get errors? Wrong output? Wrong output for certain input?

Comment: @Michal Frystacky When running, the binaray search method looks not work at all。 I guess the transformation of a 2D array's element to 1D array element is wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that's the only problem, but this code is wrong :

```
if ( column[mid]== searchItem ) {
    while ((mid - 1) >= 0) {
        if (column[mid - 1] == searchItem){ 
            mid--;
            count++;
        }
    }
    while ((mid + 1) < (column.length - 1)) {
        if (column[mid + 1] == searchItem){ 
            mid++;
            count++;
        }
    }
}
```

It basically tests all the elements of the `column` array from `mid` to `0`, and than from `0` to `column.length-1`. Not only you pass over the entire array, which defeats the purpose of your binary search, you visit all the elements between `mid` and `0` twice, which means your count is wrong.

At better approach :

```
if ( column[mid]== searchItem ) {
    count = 1;
    int temp = mid;
    while (temp > 0 && column[temp - 1] == searchItem) { 
        temp--;
        count++;
    }
    temp = mid;
    while (temp < column.length - 1 && column[temp + 1] == searchItem) {
        temp++;
        count++;
    }
}
```

The two things to note :

1. I don't modify `mid`, since we need the original value of `mid` for the second while loop.
2. I quit each while loop when I encounter an element that is not equal to `searchItem`. Since the array is supposed to be sorted (otherwise binary serarch won't work), there's no need to iterate over the entire array.

P.S. the argument called `row` in your `biSearch` is actualy an index of a column of your 2D array, so its name is confusing.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer and suggestion, I will try and test it.